# Azure DevOps Pipeline yaml with extends template cannot find template file

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 2 yaml files both sitting in a pipelines folder

TFpipeline-dv.yml

```
trigger:
- none

pr: none

variables:  
  - template: variables/pipelinevars-dv.yml

extends:
  template: TFPipeline-shared.yml
```

The template file TFPipeline-shared.yml  is as follows:

```
variables:
  - template: variables/pipelinevars-common.yml

stages:
  - stage: TF_Deploy
    displayName: TF Deployment
    dependsOn: []
    jobs: 
        more stuff follows
```

However when I try to use the first file in a Azure DevOps Pipeline I get hte following error message

*/pipelines/TFpipeline-dv.yml: File /pipelines/TFPipeline-shared.yml not found in repository https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/xxxxx/_git/LogicAppDemo002 branch refs/heads/master version asfdsafsadfsadfsadfsadfdsafsadf.*

I have checked that both file names in the references and the actual file names are correct. Yet it complains that the template file cannot be found. Also both files exist in the branch.

Any ideas?

Comment: I created pipeline files with new names and now its finding the files. Not sure what is different. Also, I had to use both the variable template lines in the same files otherwise it was complaining that I was using it twice.

Comment: Are you sure that both files are on master branch?

Comment: they are both on the same branch....yes....but as mentioned....recreating the files with a new name fixed the issue.